# Meaning of 何と何をする in this sentence

Tags: grammar, meaning

I'm currently going through the Tobira book and at chapter 3 there is this sentence:

`日本で活躍しているロボットには二つのグループがあります。何と何をするためのロボットですか。`

What's the meaning/use of 何と何をする? this is my first time seeing it. Is there any other combinations or rules for this type of question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you referring to the first question on page 64? 何と何をする can be split as ((何と何) + をする) + ため. The question is looking for the two groups of robots according to their purpose/objective or ため.

Comment: Yes, that’s the one. I get the idea of what’s being asked, but what I want to know what would be the English equivalent to 何と何, for example in jisho.org 何と is translated as what/how, so what would be 何と何? Or is there no English equivalent and it’s just used to ask for multiple reasons or similar?

Comment: 何と何をするため can translate to "for doing what and what." Nothing grammatically wrong with it in English, but not the most natural.

Comment: Thanks! Now I get it.